# Plesk Unable to exec utility listmng: Cannot find grep program System error 2: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I have a little problem with my plesk installation at the moment and unfortunately do not have enough knowledge to solve it on my own. I would therefore be glad if I could get a hint on this.

I tried to log in into my Plesk but I can't proceed due to the following error:

> Internal error: Unable to exec utility listmng: listmng: listmng: Cannot find grep program System error 2: No such file or directory
>
> File   Unix.php
>
> Line  147
>
> Type  PleskUtilException

I'm running Plesk 11.5.30 on Ubuntu 10.04. What's strange is that I didn't make any changes on the server lately. At least not that I'm aware of.

I tried running plesks "bootstrap.sh repair" and uninstalled the mailman but I keep getting the error.

When I run /opt/psa/admin/sbin/listmng via ssh I get the same error, so I guess it's not able to use the grep command. I don't know how to solve that problem though.

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I really don't understand why you were voted down as this appears to be a very valid question with regards to Plesk systems administration. I've attempted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to start off by looking if `grep` is on your system with `grep -V` which will reports the version (and if it exists in the path).

If grep is not there I would worry about the integrity of your operating system. Grep is pretty standard and normally always found in the path.

If `grep` is missing you might want to examine the path with `export` on a healthy system to see if essential system folders are missing from the path.

On my healthy Ubuntu 13.04 the path reports:

`PATH="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

On this system the `grep` utility can be located in `/bin` and the system wide path is set in `/etc/environment`.

If you don't succeed using with troubleshooting the operating system / Plesk installation I would seriously consider contacting Plesk. There *might* be a cost to logging a ticket with them but at the same time the support for their product is excellent.

And finally you could try logging the problem on the Parallels forum (http://forum.parallels.com). Although it's technical community based support it's generally very active and you might even find a Parallels engineer lurking there. I have found that although ServerFault is a great systems administration Q&A site Plesk problem are better addressed elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help here. Grep is installed system wide, however I marked your answer as accepted for pointing out that the plesk forum might be a better place to ask for plesk related questions.